# Закопчёную/закопчённую сковородку

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

`Я не ем закоплёную/закопчённую рыбчонку.`

`Я выбросил папину закопчёную/закопчённую сковородку.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно с двумя Н:

***Я не ем закопчённую рыбчонку***;

***Я выбросил папину закопчённую сковородку***.

Причастие *закопченный* пишется с двумя Н, т. к. **есть приставка -ЗА-**, которая влияет на вид глагола, от которого образовано причастие: *коптить (что делать?)* — *закоптить (что сделать?)*. Причастие, образованное от глаголов **совершенного вида**, пишутся с двумя Н.

Comment: Но во 2-м случае никто ничто не коптил. Там-то оно как отглагольное прил. используется-таки, т. е. 'сковорода, покрытая пригарью'.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр А даже в значении _покрытый копотью_ то же самое. И в том и в том две Н. И это слово, какое бы у него значение ни было, пишется с двумя Н, если есть приставка, влияющая на вид глагола, от которого оно образовпно.

Answer (score 2):

1. *Я не ем **закопчённую** рыбчонку* (причастие, значение действия).
2. *Я выбросил папину **закопчённую** (покрытую копотью) сковородку* (прилагательное, качественное значение).

**Пояснение**

Выбор НН делается по приставке ЗА и сов. виду глагола "закоптить", но части речи здесь **разные.** Папа пришел с рыбалки и **закоптил** пойманную рыбчонку. А сковородку  он не **коптил**, она давно такая.

**Словарь**

**ЗАКОПТИТЬ,** -пчу, -птишь; закопчённый; -чён, -чена, -чено; св. (нсв. коптить). что. 1. Покрыть копотью, сажей. З. стекло. З. кастрюлю. 2. Приготовить в пищу копчением (рыбу, мясо). З. рыбу. З. окорок. <Закапчивать, -аю, -аешь; нсв. Закапчиваться, -ается; страд.

**ЗАКОПЧЁННЫЙ**, -ая, -ое. Покрытый копотью, сажей; закоптелый. З-ое стекло керосиновой лампы.

Comment: Не *3-ое*, а *3-е*, Шерон.

Comment: Why is that, sir?

Comment: Because that's the right way to make numeral suffixes, and you do know that.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр  *З-ое* там не третье, а ***З**акопчённ**ое*** [*стекло*].

Comment: А почему всё равно две гласные как окончание? Почему неправильно было бы сократить как *з-е стекло*?

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр  Потому что так принято в словарях. Если форма слова в примере совпадает с начальной, пишут только первую букву: ЗАКОПТИТЬ... *З. кастрюлю*. А через дефис пишут всё то, что не совпадает.

Comment: А почему так принято?

Comment: Чтоб всё было чики-пуки.

Comment: Не... Лео хочет компенсации.  Требуется объяснение)

Comment: Пусть задаёт отдельный вопрос. А то это не по теме.

Comment: А можно так: Закопченн/ый (м.р.), а у нас закопченн/ое.  То есть нужно обозначить ср.род, окончание оставляем, а все лишнее, кроме буквы З,  срезаем.